# How to map then query nested data on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to index and query a simple nested data on elastic search but getting the following  error:

```
"filter":[]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[products] [_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }]
```

My mapping is:

```
{
  "product": {
    "properties": {
      "id": { "type": "integer", "store": true },
      "description": { "type": "string" },
      "kind": { "type": "string" },
      "name": { "type": "string", "store": true },
      "tags": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "label": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "omit_norms": true,
            "index_options": "docs"
          },
          "slug": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "omit_norms": true,
            "index_options": "docs"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm successfully getting all headphones the query below:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "match": { "kind": "Headphone" }
                    },
                    "must_not": [],
                    "should": []
                }
            },
            "filter": []
        }
    }
}
```

My question is what is the proper query structure to find "headphones with XX tag" or "headphones with XX and YY tag (another query)" while supporting facets?

I just tried to merge the query part below with the query above but i can't find out the "correct" place (key) to put it:

```
{
    "nested": {
        "path": "tags",
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "terms": {
                        "tags.slug": [ "discount", "black"],
                        "minimum_should_match": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the mapping doesn't seem to be valid. For example, correct mapping should contain `properties` instead of `mapping`. Make sure that your mapping is actually getting applied by running

```
curl "localhost:9200/products/product/_mapping?pretty"
```

The search request is missing `query` element on the top level and `minimum_should_match` is not supported by the `terms` filter. So, request should look like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "terms": {
                            "tags.slug": [ "discount", "black"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Oh thanks for your answer. There are several problems. I just updated the mapping in question and reading some documentation for now about these points..

Comment: Here is a complete working example in case you have any difficulties with figuring it out - https://gist.github.com/imotov/eb0f09a58668af4b726f